# How to sort a list of dictionaries by value when each key is different?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

While searching for an answer to this question I found that many posts were either concerned more with ordering by keys of each dictionary in a list or the dictionaries within the lists had descriptions for each value like: 
 `[{'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'sam'}]` possibly making it easier to order each dictionary.

I have a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```
[{'Emma': 20}, {'Jake': 15}, {'John': 22}]
```

How can I order this list by each users age using sorted and lambda only (if possible)?
 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `sorted(source, key=lambda x: next(iter(x.values())))`

Comment: already answererd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: is there is only one user per dictionary why are there many dictionaries in a list and not just a single dictionary? Also if you need a certain order, you probably need to switch to tuples or so

Comment: Perfect @OlvinRoght thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `next()` to get first of dict values:

```
source = [{'Emma': 20}, {'Jake': 15}, {'John': 22}]
sorted_source = sorted(source, key=lambda x: next(iter(x.values())))
```